# C# Regex Match whole word, with special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have searched through some questions but couldn't find the exact answer i am looking for. 
I have a requirement to search through large strings of text looking for keywords matches. I was using IndexOf, however, i require to find whole word matches e.g. if i search for Java, but the text contains JavaScript, it shouldn't match. This works fine using **\b{*pattern*}\b**, but if i search for something like C#, then it doesn't work.

Below is a few examples of text strings that i am searching through:

```
languages include Java,JavaScript,MySql,C#
languages include Java/JavaScript/MySql/C#
languages include Java, JavaScript, MySql, C#
```

Obviously the issue is with the special character '#'; so this also doesn't work when searching for C++.

Comment: Do you know all possible separators between terms?

Comment: No as the text i am searching is scraped off the internet. It would be normal logical word boundaries e.g. white space, comma etc

Comment: I would replace all commas and slashes (and other separator you *might* be expecting) with spaces. Then remove all duplicate spaces, then add one at the beginning and one at the end. Then just search for `" " + word + " "`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the pattern using `Regex.Escape` and replace the *context-dependent* `\b` word boundaries with `(?<!\w)` / `(?!\w)` lookarounds:

```
var rx = $@"(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(pattern)}(?!\w)";
```

The `(?<!\w)` is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a start of string or a non-word char immediately before the current location, and `(?!\w)` is a negative looahead that fails the match if there is an end of string or a non-word char immediately after the current location.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this is because there isn't a word boundary (a `\b`) after the `#`, because `#` isn't a "word" character. You could use a regular expression like the following, which searches for a character that isn't a part of a language name `[^a-zA-Z+#]` after the language:

```
\b{pattern}[^a-zA-Z+#]
```

Or, if you believe you can list all of the possible characters that aren't part of a language name (for example, whitespace, `,`, `.`, and `;`):

```
[\s,.;]{pattern}[\s,.;]
```

Alternately, if it is possible that a language name is at the very end of a string (depending on what you're getting the data from), you might need to also match the end of the string `$` in addition to the separators, or similarly, the beginning of the string `^`.

```
[\s,.;]{pattern}(?:[\s,.;]|$)
```